# Complex SQL query or queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I looked at other examples, but I don't know enough about SQL to adapt it to my needs. I have a table that looks like this:

```
    ID  Month   NAME    COUNT   First   LAST    TOTAL
  ------------------------------------------------------
    1   JAN2013 fred    4
    2   MAR2013 fred    5
    3   APR2014 fred    1
    4   JAN2013 Tom     6
    5   MAR2014 Tom     1
    6   APR2014 Tom     1
```

This could be in separate queries, but I need 'First' to equal the first month that a particular name is used, so every row with fred would have JAN2013 in the first field for example. I need the 'Last" column to equal the month of the last record of each name, and finally I need the 'total' column to be the sum of all the counts for each name, so in each row that had fred the total would be 10 in this sample data.  This is over my head. Can one of you assist?

Comment: you need to show some effort to solve this yourself.

Comment: I'm quite sure your instructor wants to see your work and not ours. If you can't get started on your assignment, ask the instructor for help. They're being paid to provide you the knowledge necessary to complete your assignments, and apparently they have not yet done so.

Comment: This isn't for a class actually.  This is for a real world problem. I just don't have time to master SQL over the weekend to transfom this data for my boss

Comment: i think you could at least solve the last part which is the easiest  ie SUM up the count column GROUP BY name. if you do there will be much more willingness to provide the rest of the solution

Comment: Whilst you think people are being unhelpful, it's more that your question isn't right for the site. It would be better posted on a traditional forum, have a read of the posting guidelines as to why this is.

Answer (score -1):

This is crude but should do the trick.   I renamed your fields a bit because you are using a bunch of "RESERVED" sql words and that is bad form.

```
;WITH cte as
(
Select
    [NAME]
    ,[nmCOUNT]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by NAME order by txtMONTH ASC) as 'FirstMonth'
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by NAME order by txtMONTH DESC) as 'LastMonth'
    ,SUM([nmCOUNT]) as 'TotNameCount'
From Table
Group by NAME, [nmCOUNT]
)

,cteFirst as
(
Select
    NAME
    ,[nmCOUNT]
    ,[TotNameCount]
    ,[txtMONTH] as 'ansFirst'
From cte
Where FirstMonth = 1
)

,cteLast as
(
Select
    NAME
    ,[txtMONTH] as 'ansLast'
From cte
Where LastMonth = 1

Select c.NAME, c.nmCount, c.ansFirst, l.ansLast, c.TotNameCount
From cteFirst c
LEFT JOIN cteLast l on c.NAME = l.NAME
```

Comment: The question is tagged as access, I think you may have missed that as this uses functions that don't exist in access, only SQL server